# C# При решении задания, компилятор выдает ошибку компиляции: error CS0019: помогите разобраться

Tags: c#, if

я только  начал изучение C#  При решении учебного  задания,  код не компилируется,  выдает  ошибку:  VectorTask.cs(43,12): error CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'double'   Не понимаю почему   символ <  не  может быть использован  в условие IF  Сам код:

```
    public static  bool IsVectorInSegment(Vector Vector,Vector End,Vector Begin)
      { 
         double c= ((Vector.X- Begin.X)/(End.X-Begin.X));
         double d= ((Vector.Y-Begin.Y)/(End.Y-Begin.Y));
         if ((( End.X< Vector.X <Begin.X)||( Begin.X< Vector.X < End.X))&&(c==d))     
         return true;
         else 
         return  false;
      }
```

Comment: `Begin.X< Vector.X < End.X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта ошибка означает, что у Вас несовместимые типа в сравнении.
То есть, около какого-то знака слева и справа стоят bool и double.
В Вашем, конкретном случае, в этой конструкции: `(End.X< Vector.X <Begin.X)`, компилятор сначала сравнивает `End.X< Vector.X`, пускай будет 5.4 < 7.4, и получает true, затем берёт это значение и сравнивает с `Begin.X` то есть `true < 12.2`, вот он и ругается, мол не могу сравнить фиолетовый цвет с креслом, а вы спрашиваете у него, что из них больше?

Решение Вашей проблемы заключается в понимании типов переменных, конструкций языка, в общем почитайте литературу, пройдите онлайн уроки, чтобы изучить азы.

Также, есть 2 решения:

1. **не очень хорошее:**
   Вместо этой строки

   ```
   if ((( End.X< Vector.X <Begin.X)||( Begin.X< Vector.X < End.X))&&(c==d))
   ```

   Вставить эту:

   ```
   if (((( End.X< Vector.X) && (Vector.X <Begin.X))||(( Begin.X< Vector.X ) && (Vector.X < End.X)))&&(c==d))
   ```
2. **Лучше:**

   Во-первых, можно удалить лишние скобки, студия их выделяет слабым серым, тогда их можно стереть без угрозы логике.
   Также, называйте локальные переменные с маленькой буквы, меньше ошибок, понятнее, что вы обращаетесь к объекту, а не к статическому классу:

   То есть, преобразуем Ваш код вот так:

   ```
   public static bool IsVectorInSegment(Vector vector, Vector end, Vector begin)
   {
       double c = (vector.X - begin.X) / (end.X - begin.X);
       double d = (vector.Y - begin.Y) / (end.Y - begin.Y);

       if (((end.X < vector.X < begin.X) || (begin.X < vector.X < end.X)) && (c == d))
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }
   ```

   Во-вторых, эту проверку `c == d` можно вынести вверх, чтобы проверки стали проще и понятнее, ведь если она не выполнится, то мы не получим true, никогда, то есть убрали ещё пару скобок, сбивающих с толку:

   ```
   public static bool IsVectorInSegment(Vector vector, Vector end, Vector begin)
   {
       double c = (vector.X - begin.X) / (end.X - begin.X);
       double d = (vector.Y - begin.Y) / (end.Y - begin.Y);

       if (c != d) return false;

       if ((end.X < vector.X < begin.X) || (begin.X < vector.X < end.X))
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }
   ```

   Далее, исправляем, Вашу, досадную ошибку:

   ```
   public static bool IsVectorInSegment(Vector vector, Vector end, Vector begin)
   {
       double c = (vector.X - begin.X) / (end.X - begin.X);
       double d = (vector.Y - begin.Y) / (end.Y - begin.Y);

       if (c != d) return false;

       if (((end.X < vector.X) && (vector.X < begin.X)) || ((begin.X < vector.X) && (vector.X < end.X)))
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }
   ```

   Далее проведем последнее преобразование, дам другой пример (для понимания), попроще:

   ```
   if (b < c)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
   ```

   Компилятор сравнивает b и c, получая, например true, дальше проверяет, true == true?, значит надо вернуть true, можно же сразу, без проверки возвращать полученное значение сравнения, то есть:

   ```
   return b < c;
   ```

   Ну, и вишенка на тортике, уберем лишний if, и в конечном итоге, получим:

   ```
   public static bool IsVectorInSegment(Vector vector, Vector end, Vector begin)
   {
       double c = (vector.X - begin.X) / (end.X - begin.X);
       double d = (vector.Y - begin.Y) / (end.Y - begin.Y);

       if (c != d) return false;

       return ((end.X < vector.X) && (vector.X < begin.X)) || ((begin.X < vector.X) && (vector.X < end.X));
   }
   ```

Comment: можно еще скобок убрать и внести `c != d` или `c == d` в общее условие

Comment: Я его как раз таки вынес, чтобы не перегружать последнее условие.